# How to compare 2 Excel columns using DataFrame then output it to another Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have this Excel [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NA3DLqsziHP6ZMuT7HWAOBmJ_xvtSn9u/view?usp=sharing). Here is the screenshot.
[image: Excel file]

I want to compare the `dataset` column with `unique-pitch` column, and then put the output to the Excel file again. The comparison is in this scenario:

1. Search for intersection (data match between `dataset` column with `unique-pitch` column) .
2. Search for data existed in `dataset` that is not existed in `unique-pitch` (difference 1).
3. Search for data not existed in `dataset` that is existed in `unique-pitch` (difference 2).

I am using row no. 0 for this example, and the rule used in this comparison is same throughout the data.

```
dataset = [0, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58]
unique-pitch = [0, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64]

# this is the expected output
Scenario 1 result = [0, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58]
Length of Scenario 1 result = 6

Scenario 2 result = [46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53]
Length of Scenario 2 result = 8

Scenario 3 result = [59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64]
Length of Scenario 3 result = 6
```

From what I know now, I can read the Excel file using **DataFrame** and find the values of 3 scenario.

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\014_twinkle_twinkle 300 0.0001 dataframe - python.xlsx')
datasets = df['dataset'].tolist()
unique_pitches = df['unique-pitch'].tolist()

i = 0
for dataset in datasets:
    print("Iteration:", i+1)
    dataset = ast.literal_eval(dataset)
    unique_pitch = ast.literal_eval(unique_pitches[i])

    # scenario 1
    scenario1_data = list(set(dataset) & set(unique_pitch))
    scenario1_len = len(scenario1_data)

    # scenario 2
    scenario2_data = list(set(dataset) - set(unique_pitch))
    scenario2_len = len(scenario2_data)

    # scenario 3
    scenario3_data =  list(set(unique_pitch) - set(dataset))
    scenario3_len = len(scenario3_data)
    
    print("Intersection\t\t: ", scenario1_data)
    print("Len Intersection\t: ", scenario1_len)
    print("Difference 1\t\t: ", scenario2_data)
    print("Len difference 1\t: ", scenario2_len)
    print("Difference 2\t\t: ", scenario3_data)
    print("Len difference 2\t: ", scenario3_len)
    print("-"*100)
    i += 1

# how to put those 6 new variables to df?

# to change df to excel
df.to_excel()
```

In my Excel output, I am expecting this kind of result.
[image: desired output]

My question is: how to read and compare the data on each column from **DataFrame** `df`, then produce the expected result to an Excel file? I read on some other post on Stack Overflow that I should not iterate the DataFrame per row because it is a slow process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start I think it is generally a good idea to first make your code work, and then research faster methods.

For scenario 1:

```
intersection = []
for value in dataset:
    if value in unique_pitch:
        intersection.append(value)
print(intersection)
print(len(intersection))
```

Scenario 2:

```
not_in_unique_pitch = []
for value in dataset:
    if value not in unique_pitch:
        not_in_unique_pitch.append(value)
print(not_in_unique_pitch)
print(len(not_in_unique_pitch))
```

I know you already fixed scenario 3 but if you want it in the same way:

```
not_in_dataset = []
for value in unique_pitch:
    if value not in dataset:
        not_in_dataset.append(value)
print(not_in_dataset)
print(len(not_in_dataset))
```

---

Edit answer to your question:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.read_excel('your.xlsx')
datasets = df['dataset'].tolist()
unique_pitches = df['unique_pitch'].tolist()

i = 0
for dataset in datasets:
    print("Iteration:", i+1)
    dataset = ast.literal_eval(dataset)
    unique_pitch = ast.literal_eval(unique_pitches[i])

    # scenario 1
    print(list(set(dataset) & set(unique_pitch)))
    print(len(list(set(dataset) & set(unique_pitch))))

    # scenario 2
    print(list(set(dataset) - set(unique_pitch)))
    print(len(list(set(dataset) - set(unique_pitch))))

    # scenario 3
    print(list(set(unique_pitch) - set(dataset)))
    print(len(list(set(unique_pitch) - set(dataset))))
    i += 1
```

---

After edited question:
With save to a excel (.xlsx):

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.read_excel('your.xlsx')
datasets = df['dataset'].tolist()
unique_pitches = df['unique_pitch'].tolist()

i = 0
scenario1_data = []
scenario2_data = []
scenario3_data = []
scenario1_len = []
scenario2_len = []
scenario3_len = []
for dataset in datasets:
    print("Iteration:", i+1)
    dataset = ast.literal_eval(dataset)
    unique_pitch = ast.literal_eval(unique_pitches[i])

    # scenario 1
    scenario1_data.append(list(set(dataset) & set(unique_pitch)))
    scenario1_len.append(len(scenario1_data[i]))

    # scenario 2
    scenario2_data.append(list(set(dataset) - set(unique_pitch)))
    scenario2_len.append(len(scenario2_data[i]))

    # scenario 3
    scenario3_data.append(list(set(unique_pitch) - set(dataset)))
    scenario3_len.append(len(scenario3_data[i]))
    
    i += 1

df['scenario 1 data'] = scenario1_data
df['scenario 2 data'] = scenario2_data
df['scenario 3 data'] = scenario3_data

df['len scenario 1 data'] = scenario1_len
df['len scenario 2 data'] = scenario2_len
df['len scenario 3 data'] = scenario3_len

df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: How to iterate and read the data from DataFrame? The ```dataset``` and ```unique-pitch``` lists must be taken from the DataFrame.

Comment: Aah sorry I think i miss understood your question. Give me a second

Comment: If I am right this will iterate through the different rows.

Comment: yay, that worked! One last thing, I've made an edit to my post based on your answer. I want to save all the data back into DataFrame again. What can I do? I've already put the column example on my post.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, but that last piece of code should work.

Comment: If you still want to print your data use scenario1_data[i] and scenario1_len[i] in the for loop.